# settings elements of matrix of functions

Tags: functions, matrix

I have a work flow that involves initially specifying a matrix function (or a matrix of functions), e.g.

`f[x_]:={{Exp[x],Sin[x]},{Cos[x],Log[x]}}`

This works well for what I am using it for. I can get specific functions through, e.g., `f[x][[1,2]]` which gives `Sin[x]`.

However, Mathematica doesn't seem to let me update elements of this matrix.

I.e. if I then do

`f[x][[1,2]]=x^2
 f[x]`

it just prints

`x^2`

`{{Exp[x],Sin[x]},{Cos[x],Log[x]}}`

as if it acknowledges what I have done, but then doesn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `ReplacePart`: e.g., `ClearAll[f]; f[x_] := {{Exp[x], Sin[x]}, {Cos[x], Log[x]}};
f[x_] = ReplacePart[f[x], {1, 2} -> x^2];` or `MapAt`:  `ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := {{Exp[x], Sin[x]}, {Cos[x], Log[x]}};
f[x_] = MapAt[x^2 &, f[x], {1, 2}];`?

Comment: What about ':='?

Comment: @kglr Thanks! `ReplacePart' appears to have been the method I was missing!